# Does the Thinkpad x1 Carbon Mobile Broadband option work with Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, mobile-broadband, broadband

I'm just wondering if the mobile broadband works once you install ubuntu and remove windows.

Comment: How about you just try it using the "Try Ubuntu" option?

Comment: I haven't purchased the machine yet, so I'm wondering if I should buy it with the option or if it's just not going to work with Ubuntu.

Comment: hey @costa, did you find the answer to this? I just purchased one and am not able to find mobile brodband in ubuntu 20.04.